# finding Moment generating function and CDF with pmf

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

The random variable X has the pmf f(-1)=1/4, f(0)=1/8, f(1)=1/4, f(2)=3/8
a) How would you draw the c.d.f with points (-2,F(-2)), (-1,F(-1)), (0,F(0)), (1,F(1)), (2, F(2)), (3,F(3))
b)Write the MGF of this distribution
c) Range of and p.m.f of X^(2)

For the cdf i tried to come up with an equation that satisfies the values but couldn't I'm guessing the cdf is the antiderivative of such equation? 
for the pmf should include f(-1)=1/4 ? i thought pmf f(x)>0

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps to format questions using Mathjax (see FAQ). Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) I do not think you are expected to give single "equation."

We have $F(-2)=\Pr(X\le -2)=0$.

Similarly, $F(-1)=\Pr(X\le -1)=\frac{1}{4}$.

Also, $F(0)=\Pr(X\le 0)=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}=\frac{3}{8}$.

Also, $F(1)=\Pr(X\le 1)=\frac{5}{8}$.

Also, $F(2)=1$. And $F(3)=1$.

To understand what we did, remember we are calculating the **cumulative** distribution function.

(2) For the moment generating function, note that we want $E(e^{Xt})$. Note that $X=-1$ with probability $\frac{1}{4}$, $X=0$ with probability $\frac{1}{8}$, $X=1$ with probability $\frac{1}{4}$, and $X=2$ with probability $\frac{3}{8}$. So $e^{Xt}$ takes values $e^{-t}$, $1$, $e^t$, and $e^{2t}$ with the probabilities just listed. The mgf is therefore
$$\frac{1}{4}e^{-t}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{4}e^{t}+\frac{3}{8}e^{2t}.$$

(3) for the mass function of $X^2$, note that $X^2$ takes on values $0$, $1$, and $4$. The event $X^2=0$ happens precisely if $X=0$ happens. The probability of this is $\frac{1}{8}$.

The event $X^2=1$ can happen in $2$ ways, if $X=-1$ and if $X=1$. Thus the probability that $X^2=1$ is $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}$.

Finally, $\Pr(X^2=4)=\frac{3}{8}$.

**Remark:** For the cumulative distribution function $F(x)$ of this kind of **discrete** distribution, the traditional integral is not of much use. In our case, $F(x)=0$ for all $x\lt -1$. Then at $x=-1$, $F(x)$ **jumps** to $\frac{1}{4}$. It remains at $\frac{1}{4}$ for all $x$ with $-1\le x\lt 0$. Then at $0$ it **jumps** to $\frac{3}{8}$, where it remains for $0\le x\lt 1$. At $1$ it jumps to $\frac{5}{8}$, then jumps to $1$ at $x=2$, and stays there for all $x\ge 2$.

Comment: thanks a lot this actually makes sense you really helped me a lot with the MGF.

Comment: You are welcome, the point of these answers is to have things make sense, so that you can solve problems of the same general character on your own. It is very important to get intuition about what the cdf really means. the function $F(x)$ gives the **total** "weight" up to and including $x$.